# how would i retrieve json data in code behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am sending json (id) to "page2.aspx" from "page1.aspx". Here's my Page1.aspx

```
(function load() {                
    return $.get("page2.aspx", {id: "123" },  function (response, status, xhr){     
            //code
    }
}
```

How would i retrieve 'id' value in page2.aspx in code-behind?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var id = ?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try:

```
 Request["id"]
```

In the code-behind of the page?  It should be accessible using that.